# nodejs how to verify the token?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

How can I verify token? this is what I've already done, and this is the error I receive

```
router.get('/user/ApplicationAccess/:intapplicationid/:intuserid/:token', UsersApplicationAccess);

async function UsersApplicationAccess(req, res, next){
   
    params = req.params;

    console.log(params);

    let validation_rules = {
        intapplicationid: 'required',
        intuserid: 'required',
        token: 'required'
    };

    let validation = new Validator(params, validation_rules);
    console.log("params", params);

    if(validation.passes())
    {
        try
        {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(params.token, pem, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decodedToken) {
                let results = await Access.ApplicationAccess(params);
                //console.log("results: ", results)
                res.status(200).json(results.rows);
            });

        }catch(err){
            console.log("-----result data error-----\n", err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }else{
        res.status(400).json(validation.errors);
    }

}
```

error

> let results = await Access.ApplicationAccess(params);
> ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level
> bodies of modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this function to be async:

```js
async function(err, decodedToken) {
  let results = await Access.ApplicationAccess(params);
  //console.log("results: ", results)
  res.status(200).json(results.rows);
}
```

Or you could also do this:

```js
function(err, decodedToken) {
  Access.ApplicationAccess(params).then(results => {
    res.status(200).json(results.rows);
  });
}
```